# How to change settings for SQL Developer to correctly recognize current version of SDK

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, java-6

I've installed Oracle 11g r2 to my machine and when I opened Oracle SQL Developer it says: `java 1.6.0_02 is not supported` and telling me to install new java version.

Then I've installed JDK 1.6.0_27 and set the path in environment variables and run Oracle SQL Developer again, but the same error occurred.

How can I change the settings for Oracle SQL Developer to recognize 1.6.0_27 as my SDK?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: i'm using windows 7 32bit and oracle 11g v2

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`sqldeveloper.conf` under `sqldeveloper/bin` in the SQLDeveloper base directory has an entry for the java home being used.

(So, on Windows, if you have unzipped SQLDeveloper to `C:\sqldev` then `sqldeveloper.conf` is under `C:\sqldev\sqldeveloper\bin`)

Something like:

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
```

Quit SQLDeveloper, remove this entry and relaunch SQLDeveloper. You should be prompted for the location of Java.

Comment: If that doesn't work, do the same in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\<version>\product.conf`... this was the file the sql developer accessed.

Answer (score 58):

In windows 10, I needed to go to following folder and change following product.conf file and set SetJavaHome directive.

```
%APPDATA%\sqldeveloper\<product-version>\product.conf
```

in my machine:

```
C:\Users\ati_o\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\17.4.0\product.conf
```

with following line.

```
SetJavaHome C:\Tools\oraclejdk8
```

Thanks to comment from @thatjeffsmith, in MacOS or Linux/Unix, go to:

```
$HOME/.sqldeveloper/<product-version>/product.conf
```

to set same SetJavaHome directive.

Comment: This is the correct answer for any version of SQL Developer 4 and higher. On a mac or *NIX, go to the .sqldeveloper folder in your $HOME dir to find the product.conf file

Comment: This worked for me in a Windows 10 machine, setting the java home in sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf didn't solve the issue

Comment: There's just 1 problem - the `.sqldeveloper` dir doesn't exist when I get the error message.

Answer (score 8):

Go to sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin and edit sqldeveloper.conf file.

There you'll see

```
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
```

Change it to correct jdk path

Comment: when i'm trying to save sqldeveloper.conf file it says "Please check whether if this fileis opened in another program"??

Comment: if you have sql developer running close it before saving this file? If sql developer is not running restart your computer, edit this file and only then try starting sql developer

Comment: @Lak1357 Old comment, but for future reference: Might also mean your editor needs admin/other rights to write to the file.

Comment: I have installed the 32 bit version and then set the path it didn't work then i installed the 64 bit version of it and it work fine.

Comment: In my case the `SetJavaHome` line was just absent.  I added it as the first line in the `.conf` file, providing it with the path for Oracle Jdk 11 and it worked,

Answer (score 6):

With SQL Developer 19.1 (2018) I tried to install it with Java 11 but it failed, so for luck I still have an old java 8 version jdk8u202-b08. 
If that happens you need to remove this folder

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper
```

And then run the exe again

```
C:\..\sqldeveloper-19.1\sqldeveloper.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the SetJavaHome Variable in AppData\Roaming worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Oracle just made a dumb installation package to makes us waste our time...good job guys!!!

The thing is, there should be a wizard/installer to configure the java path, this is because the jdk that comes pre-configured just doesn't work. Personally, I had to edit to the `sqldeveloper.conf`
under    `sqldeveloper\bin` just has ***Nivas*** said and change the pre-configured path "`SetJavaHome ../../jdk`" to "`SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`" - for earlier versions of sqldeveloper it's a requirement to have Java8 and be sure that if you install SQLDeveloper x64 version that the java version that you set in your path is also x64.

Answer (score 3):

## If you have MacOS:

->SQLDeveloper didn't worked on 15.0.1.(Oracle has mentioned that Developer supports either Oracle JDK 8 or 11.)

->Install JDK8 https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html (macOSx64)

->Go to **cd /Users/amritshukla/.sqldeveloper/20.4.1**

->Edit product.conf to add this line: **SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home**

->Launch SQLDeveloper

Answer (score 2):

This workaround helped many people (including me) during the last 12 months, so you must try it if you still have the problem:

- Go to sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin folder and locate "msvcr100.dll"
- Copy this dll to C:\Windows\System32 folder

Obs: you will need to provide administrator authorization to finish the file copy, so you must be logged on as a true windows administrator.

After copying the file, just try to start the sqldeveloper again. No reboot needed.

Hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 2):

If you have MacOS :

1. Get the JDK home path 
   eg: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home`
2. Go to 
   eg : `cd /Users/sarath_sukumaran/.sqldeveloper/19.2.1`
3. Edit product.conf to set SetJavaHome
   eg : `SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home`
4. Re-open the SQL Developer and check the Java version from **'About Oracle SQL Developer' > Version**

Answer (score 1):

Adding a solution for Mac.

Edit this file: `/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/jdk.conf`

Uncomment the below line for SetJavaHome and give it the full path to JDK1.8. As of today, it does not work with JDK 11.

```
# By default, the product launcher will search for a JDK to use. If you wish
# to specify a JDK to use for all users of this install, uncomment the line
# below and set the path the the preferred JDK
#
# SetJavaHome /path/jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL developer > 4.x you can find this setting at this location on windows:

```
<USER HOME PATH>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\<VERSION>\product.conf
```

and change `SetJavaHome` to your JDK path. You can get the user home path on the command prompt using %homepath%.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of other answers:

For macOS 12.3.1 (M1 processor), SQL Developer 21.4.3, using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/jdks#zulu) to install [Zulu 11](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-11-lts&os=macos&package=jdk).

1. `mkdir -p ~/.sqldeveloper/21.4.3` (this directory didn't exist so I had to create it)
2. `echo 'SetJavaHome $HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.15-zulu/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home' >> ~/.sqldeveloper/21.4.3/product.conf`

Comment: This worked for me. Additional notes:
1. You can find your version of SQLDeveloper like so: `cat /Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/version.properties`
2. You can also use `$JAVA_HOME`: `echo "SetJavaHome $JAVA_HOME" > ~/.sqldeveloper/21.4.3/product.conf`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install the latest Oracle SQL Developer. Link @ [SQL Developer Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) . This installation will install and use the latest Java version 1.8.x.

The sqldeveloper.conf file resides at a newer location at ...\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin .

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the version of SDK linked to your SQL developer, uninstall the other versions of SDK and install the required version. Once you install the required version, try running SQL developer it will automatically prompt you to attach the path. ANd you can provide the new path.

Answer (score 0):

None of the sqldeveloper.conf had an entry in my case, and i downloaded another zip installation, which gave me same error for same JDK versoin, without me configuring anything, S

COMPANY=Oracle
PRODUCT=SQL Developer
VERSION=19.01000942042f
VER=19.1.0
VER_FULL=19.1.0.094.2042
BUILD_LABEL=094.2042
BUILD_NUM=094.2042
EDITION=

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** I was getting following error when try to open oracle sql developer

```
---------------------------
Oracle SQL Developer
---------------------------
Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine
Located at path:
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

**Resolution:**

- File msvcr100.dll was missing in the location ***C:\Program
  Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\bin***.
- Hence
  copied that file from **C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100.dll** TO
  **C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot\jre\bin***
- This helped me to lauch the oracle SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux OS(UBUNTU).
Then after installation go to ./sqldeveloper and find the product.conf file and change the "#SetJavaHome" to "SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/" dont forget to remove the '#'
Generally in Ubuntu, the path for any version of jre installed is /usr/lib/jvm/.

The path of the installed sqlDeveloper is "cd /opt/sqldeveloper" and launch "ssh sqldeveloper.sh"