# Unsupported Java Version for Oracle SQL D

Tags: oracle

I have a problem when I run `Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.1 (4.0.1.14.48)` :

[image]

I searched about this issue, and I found this post :

[How to change settings for SQL Developer to correctly recognize current version of SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385550/oracle-and-jdk-problem)

So I folowed the instructions in it , I modified `SetJavaHome` to `SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386`

in `/usr/lib/jvm` I have this :

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-common  java-7-openjdk-i386
java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-i386
```

So jdk 1.7 is already installed.

But I still get the same error message!

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running on Windows.In this case it happens because the Sql Developer actually reads the `SetJavaHome` from "product.conf" file instead of the file you are modifying.

Open the file explorer, type %appdata% and hint Enter. The file "product.conf" is at "\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\". Modify the `SetJavaHome` on it and everything goes fine.