# SQL Developer with JDK (64 bit) cannot find JVM

Tags: java, windows-8.1, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just wasted one morning trying to get SQL developer to work on my current setup:

- OS: Windows 8.1 virtual machine running on mac via Parallels.
- No oracle client or instant client installed
- No Java installed

The reproducible steps are

- I downloaded SQL Developer for Windows with JDK (all 64-bit) and unzipped it to C:/Program Files/.
- I double clicked on C:/Program Files/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.exe

I get the following message:

> Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine
> Located at path:
> C:/Program Files/sqldeveloper/jdk/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll

Can someone please help me? I also tried first installing Java 1.8 (64 bit) and then the SQL developer version without Java. This doesn't work either. When I select the location of the JDK home, it also sent one error message saying that it couldn't find any JVMs where I said. To add insult to injury, every time I follow this procedure, the Panda antivirus tells me that sqldeveloper is infected, deletes the file and encourages me to restart.

Can someone please help me? I would mostly appreciate.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390562/oracle-sqldeveloper-jdk-path

Comment: Although similar, both questions are not the same. I also tried everything they suggested and I still get the error. Note that it finds the jdk. It says it cannot launch it

Comment: Does it indicate *why* it can't launch it - is there a details button, or a log? Do your VM memory settings allow for the SQL Developer config's JVM size? Just a thought that it might be that config that is a problem. (And not really relevant, but you know you can run SQL Developer directly on your Mac?)

Comment: Unfortunatelty, there is no details button and I can't find any logs. About your comment, I know, but the application I'm writing can only work on windows and I am preparing the setup for a full windows environment

Comment: OK, can you add your Windows VM memory allocation setting from Parallels? (From Configure->General in the control centre)

Answer (score 118):

I had the same problem and solved it by copying the `MSVCR100.dll` file from `sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin` to the `sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin` folder.

Credit goes to Erik Anderson from [SQL Developer failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891347/sql-developer-failed-to-start)

---

Note that different versions of SQL Developer need different versions of `MSVCR*.dll`. Various comments below have offered which versions worked for them.

Comment: Damn. That worked for me too!
How you even thought of that is beyond me.

Comment: Funny seems an easy thing to fix, and yet I still need to do this so it works. Using SQL Developer 4.2

Comment: Just in case it catches some people out I download SQL 3.0 and the file name was`MSVCR71.dll` but the copy and paste thing still works

Comment: I found and copied the dll from c:\windows because my installation of sql developer dint't include the jre.

Comment: I needed top copy these files: msvcr71.dll, msvcrt.dll

Comment: Thanks @PhilipConnell. I'm on v3.1 and also needed `MSVCR71.dll`.

Comment: Really crazy, I just copied c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\System\msvcr100.dll to c:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin\ - and all of a sudden, it works!

Answer (score 30):

Create directory `bin` in

```
D:\sqldeveloper\jdk\
```

Copy

```
msvcr100.dll
```

from

```
D:\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin
```

to

```
D:\sqldeveloper\jdk\bin
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was stuck at it for a while.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue when opening the sql developer it gave me the below error

> Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine due to missing file **MSVCR100.DLL**

I was using JDK 8 and windows 64 bit version. Also I downloaded the oracle sql developer software with no jdk/jre option since I already have jdk 8 installed in my system. While double clicking the sqldeveloper.exe file, it asked me to input the path of the JDK. I gave the path and then it gave me the  JVM MSVCR100.DLL error.

I checked inside the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre\bin and couldnt find the MSVCR100.DLL file there.

Then after searching the [microsoft forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52f0bd37-9a08-41b6-bb43-fa01ef3ebc4a/msvcr100dll-is-missing?forum=w8itprogeneral), understood this dll is part of the [64Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523).

After installing the above microsoft package I am able to find the dll under C:\Windows\System32

Then did the below,

- **Copied the C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100.dll --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre\bin**

This resolved the error and I was able to open up the Oracle SQL developer when it found the right dll.

Comment: This solved the same problem I had for sqldeveloper version 18.4.0.376

Answer (score 11):

If folder `sqldeveloper/jdk` doesn't contain folder `bin`, 
you can copy folder `bin` from folder `sqldeveloper/jdk/jre` into `sqldeveloper/jdk`.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Worked like charm for sql developer 4.2 on oracle 12c.

Comment: Worked like a charm for sql developer Version 3.2.20.09 as well.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the issue, whether it's **JAVA home path** not correctly set or missing **msvcr100.dll** file, follow the below methods to rectify the problem:

**1. Issue with JAVA home path not correctly set:**

Follow these steps:

- Go to directory where **SQL Developer** is installed.
- Open the `/bin` directory.
- Open `sqldeveloper.conf` in any editor to edit.
- Remove the complete line starting with "`SetJavaHome`"
- If you see: `SetJavaHome ../../jdk`, this is probably the wrong config file.

  - Instead, for try something like: `C:\Users\${username}\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\4.2.0\product.conf`
  - Or: `C:\Users\${username}\Application Data\sqldeveloper\4.2.0\product.conf`
- Save and close the file
- Start **SQL Developer** again.
- Provide the JAVA_HOME path, e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`

  - Important: Do not include suffix `\bin\java.exe`
  - Important: If running 32-bit SQL Developer, be sure to use a 32-bit JVM.  (Same for 64-bit.)

**2. Issue with missing msvcr100.dll file:**

OP stated the following in his comments below:

> If I first install the jdk and then sql developer without Java, it
> tells me Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Located at path:
> C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/msvcr100.dll

So, the error message is clear:

```
Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Located at path: 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/msvcr100.dll
```

Follow these steps:

copy:

```
MSVCR100.dll
```

from:

```
sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin
```

to:

```
sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin
```

And relaunch SQL Developer again.

**What is msvcr100.dll file?**:

`msvcr100.dll` is a part of Microsoft Visual C++ and is required to run programs developed with **Visual C++**. Some applications like **SQL Developer** in the question, needs the file in the SQL Developer installation folder.

**What options are available to fix the issue?**:

Copying it from Windows systemfolder to the installation folder of application should fix the problem. Also, you could add the PATH to the msvcr100.dll file based on 32/64 bit requirements. If the local file itself is deleted or corrupt by any chance, then it could be downloaded online or could also be reinstalled via Microsoft visual C++ 2010 Redistributable package. It is important to use the correct version based on the software. Use the 32bit dll file for 32bit software, and 64bit dll file for 64bit software.

Comment: By the way, I installed sqldeveloper-4.1.1.19.59-x64.zip (with java 1.8)

Comment: Is the JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly set? Point to that of Oracle installation directory where java resides.

Comment: As I said, I do not have an Oracle installation. I believed you don't need it for installing SQL Developer

Comment: You don't need any other Oracle components to be installed; SQL Developer *is* the client, and is self-contained (apart from the JDK). And it doesn't use the environment JAVA_HOME, since it stores its own path.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I am still stuck with the errors. If I first install the jdk and then sql developer without Java, it tells me Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Located at path: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/msvcr100.dll

Comment: @AlexPoole I intentionally wrote that for OP to come to the JRE vs JDK stuff, you spoiled my game. LOL! Just kidding :-)

Comment: Ah sorry *8-) The error message indicates it is using the JDK path though.

Comment: Tried this solution - didn't help whatsoever, but the above with 90upvotes did help. Interestingly, when you google this question - strangely this answer pops up even though this one is not very helpful

Comment: @javagirl The original answer was based on OP's error details in the question. Later, OP stated more details in the comment section and I have made an update to my answer. `msvcr100.dll` file should ideally be present just like any other Microsoft run time libraries. However, SQL Developer in certain distributions has this dll file missing. This file could also be download online or copied from other location if available locally on the system.

Answer (score 5):

Today I try to use oracle client 64 and failed connect Connection Identifier which is defined at [tnsnames.ora file](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007). I assume that  try to connect Oracle 32 Bit Server using SQL Developer 64 bit. That is why I install new jdk x86 and trying to change jdk path but this error happened:

[image: msvcr100.dll error]

Trying to download SQL Developer 32 Bit, but at the [site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-windows-1969674.html) said that the bundle support both 32 bit and 64 bit depend on java installed.

> **Windows 32-bit/64-bit**: This archive. will work on a 32 or 64 bit
>   Windows OS. The bit level of the JDK you install will determine if it
>   runs as a 32 or 64 bit application. This download does not include the
>   required Oracle Java JDK. You will need to install it if it's not
>   already on your machine.

My java home is 64 bit. New installed 32 bit jdk is not set at java home.

I need to open `$User_dir\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\version\product.conf`

Remove line `SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`

Start `sqldeveloper.exe` instead of `sqldeveloper64W.exe`

New popup will shown and choose java home to new jdk version (32 bit mine) :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
```

My fault, I pin `sqldeveloper64W.exe` to taskbar, why that error occured then after I move cursor and it was `sqldeveloper64W.exe`, I try to click `sqldeveloper.exe`, then I found that my setting is goes well.

So check it maybe it was happened on your system too. If `sqldeveloper.exe` does not working, try to choose `sqldeveloper64W.exe`.

Now I can call my Connection Identifier which is defined at tnsnames.ora using new setting SQL developer 32 bit mode.

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same error message when trying to install SQL Developer from *"Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included"* zip file in my Windows 10 Enterprise.

Launching the most recent SQL Developer version 4.1.3 in Windows 10 shows an error:

```
Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Located at path:
C:\Users\<USER>\Downloads\sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

The path exists and is valid.

The same zip file works on Windows 7 Professional.

The problem was a missing `msvcr100.dll`.

I simply copied `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\msvrc100.dll` to `C:\Users\<USER>\Downloads\sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\` and SQL Developer started to work.

The details can be found from [Issue running SQL Developer x64 4.1.3 with JDK](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3897502).

Funny that Oracle VirtualBox team can include the dll into the installation package but Oracle SQL Developer team can't.

Comment: My (fresh) copy of JDK/JRE didn't even come with msvcr100.dll. I had to get a copy from c\windows\system32\

Answer (score 2):

This is because sqldeveloper.conf has an entry for the java home being used

[look at this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385550/oracle-and-jdk-problem)

Comment: As I said, this is not the problem because it finds the jvm but it cannot launch it. The panda antivirus insists that sqldeveloper64W.exe has a virus

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the steps and it worked just fine.

1) Open the file present at :  \sqldeveloper-3.2.20.09.87\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf and delete the line with setJavaHome xxx .

2) Click on Sqldeveloper.exe now and browse for the java.exe present in \sqldeveloper-3.2.20.09.87\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin

3) This should launch SqlDeveloper now.

Thanks.

Comment: The point here is to point on the java.exe binary under Oracle client installation and not the JDK installation under Program Files.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Users: If anyone downloaded a non-jre version and faced issue, then later trying with the JRE version and still facing the issue, you need to delete SQLDeveloper folder inside "%AppData%\sqldeveloper". After deleting try opening sqldeveloper.exe again.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you might not have enough memory allocated to your Windows VM. If the JVM is configured to use more (maximum) memory than is available then you'll get this sort of error message.

You can read more about SQL Developer's memory [at (that) Jeff Smith's blog](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/06/configuring-memory-usage-in-oracle-sql-developer/).

The default settings still seem to be `-Xms128m -Xmx800m`. I can generate a similar error by setting -Xmx to be large than the physical RAM in my (physical) PC. So with the default settings, you will have problems if you don't have 800m of memory allocated to Windows. That doesn't seem like much, but it seems to be in the recommended window [based on this knowledgebase article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/113649).

While you could attempt to reduce the JVM requirements in your `product.conf` file that will likely lead to other issues later, if it works at all. So increase your Windows VM memory allocation, reboot, and try to launch SQL Developer again.

Answer (score 1):

Create directory "bin" in

D:\sqldeveloper\jdk\
Copy

msvcr100.dll
from

D:\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin
to

D:\sqldeveloper\jdk\bin

Answer (score 0):

I know that people may frown on a youtube example but this worked for me and I was getting the same issue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ex1dyu0Px8U

It will direct you to add the correct Environmental Variables for the JDK.

System Properties>Advanced>Environment Variables>Path>
\sqldeveloper\jdk\bin
AND
\sqldeveloper\jdk\bin\server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:
The point here is to point on the java.exe binary under Oracle client installation and not the JDK installation under Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

Installing jdk1.8.0_211 and setting the below variable in **product.conf** (located in C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\19.1.0) to JDK8 home worked for me

> SetJavaHome D:\jdk1.8.0_211

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the sqldeveloper that comes with the Oracle installation under:

```
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper
```

I tried most of the suggestions in this post to no avail, so I downloaded the one from [oracle's download page](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html) (you must register) which asks for the **location of the jdk folder** (rather than the location of java.exe).  This worked for me without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the file in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\bin`. My sqldeveloper came without jre at all so what it worked for me was copying the file from an older Oracle jre release to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, go to C:\Users<you>\AppData\Roaming, delete the whole folder [sqldeveloper]

Step 2, click on your shortcut sqldeveloper to start Sql developer

Step 3, the window will popup again to ask for a JRE location, choose a suitable one.

If it still doesn't work, execute again from step 1 to 3, remember to change JRE location every time until it works.