# SQLdeveloper doesn't start

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to run SQLdeveloper,  appears window with text "Please specify the path to the Java JDK home (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk):". I enter my path, window appear again. I enter my path again, and that's all. Nothing happens. What I should do for SQLDeveloper start?

1. JAVA_HOME set to H:\programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_11 .
2. File sqldeveloper.conf has text "SetJavaHome..."
3. C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\1.0.0.0.0\product.conf has text "SetJavaHome..." too.

Comment: Try Including the /bin in your Java path and see if it makes any difference as I have it on my system,

Comment: Start that program from the console to get printed exceptions.

Comment: **LearningPhase**, no difference.

Comment: **Tom**, no exceptions

Comment: Have you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891347/sql-developer-failed-to-start/35208418#35208418?

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to set java classpath in order to run sqldeveloper.**
**Steps To Set java ClassPath**
1.Right click on mycoputer.
2.Select Properties.
3.Left side of the my computer properties select Advanced System Settings.
4.Select Environment Variables.
5.Select path in System variables.
6.Click edit, at the end of the text add ; then past your java/bin path.
   in my system it is--> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
7.Now open your sqldeveloper, it will open for sure.

Comment: **nagaraj s** it doesn't open :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the java.exe and javaw.exe in the following path
   "**C:\Windows\System32**"
2. Set Environmental Settings for your account or for the entire system if you are a admin
3. Setting for Entire System

> - Mycomputericon >Right click>select properties>select Advanced System Properties>click Advanced Tab>click Environmental Variables>create a
>     System variable names "**JAVA_HOME**"(any thing can be given but
>     specific to name is better) in Vairable Name and for Value give the
>     JDK path up to "bin"
>
> -Put **JAVA_HOME** in the **Path** vairable's value.

4. For User Variable same process but in UserVariable section

Hope this helps!

.

Answer (score 0):

I think supported library files of sqldeveloper in your system are deleted,affected by virus or corrupted. So download fresh copy of sqldeveloper and try again.