# Unable to launch JDeveloper for missing msvcr100.dll

Tags: java, jdeveloper, msvcr100.dll

I was trying to set up Oracle SOA Suite on my PC. After extracting the jar files and running CMD as administrator, the installation proceeds smoothly until JDeveloper is launched. The application does not start at all:

```
Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Located at path: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin\msvcr100.dll
```

I really don't understand how this can be possible. I checked, this library is, in fact, present within the desired path, I have no idea what to do.

I would like to know if by any chance there is a way to be able to launch JDeveloper correctly and resolve this missing library error that is actually not missing.

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181438/sql-developer-with-jdk-64-bit-cannot-find-jvm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Developer with JDK (64 bit) cannot find JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181438/sql-developer-with-jdk-64-bit-cannot-find-jvm). Proposing the same duplicated than @ozkanpakdil mentioned

Comment: Guys it's not for SQLDeveloper, it's for JDeveloper, is it the same thing?

Comment: @PIERPAOLOZAPPIA error is same, jdeveloper is not same but both created by Oracle, probably fallowed same structure, so you just need to copy some dll from jdeveloper to jdk folder I guess, can you try the answers from there ?

Comment: The question and solution are very similar, but still distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions that Jdeveloper 12.2.1.4 on Windows 10 is the use case, the issue can be resolved by copying `C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100.dll` to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\msvcr100.dll`

Note that this is the Java install used to install/run JDevloper and not the one installed with JDeveloper.

Oracle Data Integrator 12.2.1.4 has the same issue and solution.

SQLDeveloper has a similar issue, but requires the dll be placed elsewhere (See [SQL Developer with JDK (64 bit) cannot find JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181438/sql-developer-with-jdk-64-bit-cannot-find-jvm))